# No repository field

Tags: npm

C:\Users\w10\Desktop\Natours>npm install autoprefixer --save-dev
npm WARN natours@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\postcss-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- autoprefixer@10.2.4
  updated 1 package and audited 543 packages in 3.144s

21 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 1 high severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: What was the command you have tried?

Comment: npm install autoprefixer --save-dev

Comment: The `warning` you are seeing is for an Optional Dependency package. I think this shouldn't have any impact on your project.  Did you try to use `autoprefixer` in your project?

Comment: try to do "npm init" followed by install and finally audit

Comment: Thank you so much I solved the problem.